# LINQ query return same result despite different datasources

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying the following :

```
int[] numbers = { 12, 14, -12, -8, 0, 17 };

    var pos =    from number in numbers
                    where number > 0
                    select number;

    Console.WriteLine  ( "- - - All numbers - - - " );
    foreach (var number in numbers)
        Console.Write ( "{0} " , number );

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine ( "- - - Positive numbers ( First ) - - -" );
    foreach ( var number in pos )
        Console.Write("{0} ", number);

    Console.WriteLine();
    numbers = new int[]{ 12, 14, -12, -8, 0, 17, 11, 10, -30, -15 };
    Console.WriteLine("- - - All numbers - - - ");
    foreach (var number in numbers)
        Console.Write("{0} ", number);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("- - - Positive numbers ( Second ) - - -");
    foreach (var number in pos)
        Console.Write("{0} ", number);
```

Despite i change the elements in the array, i obtain the following results :

```
- - - All numbers - - -
12 14 -12 -8 0 17
- - - Positive numbers ( First ) - - -
12 14 17
- - - All numbers - - -
12 14 -12 -8 0 17 11 10 -30 -15
- - - Positive numbers ( Second ) - - -
12 14 17
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping through `pos` in the second last `foreach`. It remembers a result from the least run. If you want a new result, you have to query `numbers` again before you print the result. Just do

```
Console.WriteLine();
numbers = new int[]{ 12, 14, -12, -8, 0, 17, 11, 10, -30, -15 };
Console.WriteLine("- - - All numbers - - - ");
foreach (var number in numbers)
    Console.Write("{0} ", number);

pos = from number in numbers
      where number > 0
      select number;

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("- - - Positive numbers ( Second ) - - -");
foreach (var number in pos)
    Console.Write("{0} ", number);
```

I would propose to use the following instead, though.

```
foreach (var number in numbers.Where(n => n > 0))
    Console.Write("{0} ", number);
```

**EDIT:**

This is one way to go.

```
Func<int, bool> comparer = n => n > 0;
foreach (var number in Compare(numbers, comparer))
            System.Console.Write("{0} ", number);
```

`Compare` method being

```
public IEnumerable<int> Compare(IEnumerable<int> source, Func<int, bool> comparer)
{
    return source.Where(comparer);
}
```

You could write an extension method as well. So many possible ways depending on what direction you want to go.

Comment: But 'pos' query variable is assigned to query expression that uses 'numbers' as data source.So looping again through 'numbers' will use the new elements.Am i wrong ?

Comment: No, you got it wrong. It is not assigned to a query expression, it is assigned to results. I will show you how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are not re-generating **pos** the second time. So, the **pos** you are showing the second time is actually the first **pos** generated.

Change the second part of the code to:

```
Console.WriteLine();
numbers = new int[]{ 12, 14, -12, -8, 0, 17, 11, 10, -30, -15 };
Console.WriteLine("- - - All numbers - - - ");
foreach (var number in numbers)
    Console.Write("{0} ", number);

pos =    from number in numbers
                where number > 0
                select number;

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("- - - Positive numbers ( Second ) - - -");
foreach (var number in pos)
    Console.Write("{0} ", number);
```

It should solve your problem. Though it is not a good practice.

EDIT: Sorry, I missed to notice that you already have accepted an answer.